# Visual Studio 2015 slow debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015, lag

When I press Step over button (F10 by default) next 5 seconds my cursor moves like I have 3 fps. Very slow, with long delay (1-2 sec). But at the same time VS debugger feels good. I can spam Step over 10 times without any delay.

The things I have  done:
Reboot
Unchecked VS settings: Enable diagnostic tools, Show
    elapsed time PerfTip

Comment: Is it a particular line of code that causes this slow down, or is it just any line?  Is this a multi-threaded application, and if so are any of the other threads busy?

Comment: Any line of code trigger slow down. Its simple app without multi-thread, but contains WPF GUI. Also computer have enough free RAM and CPU not busy.

Comment: @virty are you using VS 2015 with update 3? which is the latest update version, if yours is not, please install it and give it a try.

Comment: I use update 3 version

Comment: @virty What kind of project are you debugging? If it’s not about debugging JaveScript you could disable the option: "Enable Javascript debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome and IE)" under debugging menu. 
And also try to disable IntelliTrace, Tools -> Options -> IntelliTrace to uncheck Enable IntelliTrace.

Comment: WPF gui application. I am downloading VS 2017, will check it

Comment: @virty Hope it works well in VS2017. Any improvement or still facing the same issue?

Comment: There are no difference between 2017 and 2015. Added a solution of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Low lvl mouse hook makes my debugging slow. 
I took code from [Global mouse event handler](https://questionfocus.com/global-mouse-event-handler.html)

After this code reached every breakpoint hit blocking mouse cursor for random time from 5 sec to 60 sec

```
MouseHook.Start();
MouseHook.MouseAction += () =>
            {
               Action();
            };
```